# How to make a batch file edit a text file

Tags: batch-file, scripting, dos

I got the code

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "C:\test\file.txt"
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(strLine,"ex3")> 0 Then
        strLine = Replace(strLine,"ex3","ex5")
    End If 
    WScript.Echo strLine
Loop
```

The strLine replacing part i can fix myself to use with my own purposes, but how do i do something like this so that it doesn't require the file's name, it just edits all text files within the document?

Comment: You can pass in the file name as a parameter to your script.  But what do you mean by "edits all text files within a document"?

Comment: within the folder, i was speed typing. i do apologize, but i ment all text files within the folder that will be in the "strFile" line.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this,

```
strFolder = "c:\myfolder"
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
For Each strFile In objFolder.Files
    strFileName =strFile.Name
    strFilePath = strFile.Path
    strFileExt = objFS.GetExtensionName(strFile)
    If strFileExt = "txt" Then
        Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
            ' your current code here..
        objFile.Close()
    End If
Next
```